# How to create a nodejs microservices project in intellij?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, microservices

The problem is that let's say I want to start multiple services (several `npm start`) concurrently, it would be inconvenient to run the services as separate projects. I want to have a folder structure similar to the following under one project workspace:

```
project
├── service1
│   ├── node_modules
│   │   ├── @module1
│   │   └── @module2
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── public
│   └── src
├── service2
│   ├── node_modules
│   │   ├── @module1
│   │   └── @module2
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── public
│   └── src
└── service3
    ├── node_modules
    │   ├── @module1
    │   └── @module2
    ├── package-lock.json
    ├── package.json
    ├── public
    └── src
```

What would be a clean way to do so? I need to start multiple services together and obviously debug any in a convenient fashion if a possibility exists.

Comment: [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently)

Comment: care to elaborate?

Comment: Folder structure is fine. In case if you just need to run multiple services locally, on different ports, you can create a package.json on the root level of your project (on project folder level), install package `concurrently` and start multiple services in one command from the root level.

In case your services bind the same port in the code, you might need a workaround. For instance wrap every microservice in docker container and start them through Dockercompose. But might be overkill for you case ‍♂️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) or [Nx](https://nx.dev/).
Both are tools that manage mono-repo microservices.

There are some subtle differences between them, but essentially both do the same thing.

- They offer ways to share dependencies between your microservices.
- They offer ways to created shared libraries.
- They offer ways to **launch
  multiple services together.**

#### Lerna

One of the subtle differences, is that Nx will force you to use a single `package.json` in your root folder, essentially forcing you to use the same dependencies for all microservices. By contrast, Lerna still allows a specific `package.json` in each individual folder, which seems to resemble your current directory structure better.

In general, I think Lerna is a safe choice. And you can find a good tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-monorepos-with-lerna).

#### Nx

On the other hand, even though Lerna has been around for a longer time it has some quirks at times. I believe Nx is probably technically a more robust solution.

However, I must admit that I've mostly seen it being used for mono-repo front-end projects, and less often for back-ends. Technically, it should be able to handle both.

To get you started with Nx, you could follow [this](https://nx.dev/getting-started/node-tutorial) tutorial.

*Spoiler: Nx has commands like `nx run-many` that can help you to execute multiple services together. After migrating to nx, you could then put that command in your `"start":` script of the `package.json`, so that `npm run start` and `npm start` will execute it.*